# Simplest way to make a hash from method calls

Tags: ruby, dictionary, dry

I have code like this:

```
class Foo

  # (method definitions)

  def make_hash
    {
      some_method: some_method,
      some_other_method: some_other_method 
    }
  end

end
```

How could I simplify, or DRY, `make_hash`? I want something like `slice` or Rails' `attributes.slice`, but applying to methods of a regular class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create the hash with a default value block:

```
def methods_hash
    @methods_hash ||= Hash.new {|hash, key| hash[key] = self.class.instance_method(key) }
end
```

So, each time you request the hash's key, it will dynamically load the instance_method without having to front load it all. The instance_method method returns objects, so you might want to `.to_s` or `.to_sym` to suit your needs.

I'm intrigued by the question though and would be interested in knowing what your end goal is with this method.

Comment: Thanks. To answer your question, I simply want a way to serialize to a public JSON representation, where certain public properties are internally method results, rather than attributes.

Comment: Actually `to_json(methods: ....)` might also accomplish it, though that's specific to JSON format.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this will help.

```
mlist = {}

Foo.instance_methods(false).each do |name|
  mlist[name] = Foo.instance_method(name)
end
```